# How to have <XAxis /> use the index position of the data for dataKey recharts

Tags: reactjs, json, recharts

I am currently learning my way around recharts and I'm trying to create a zoom and highlight graph.  I want my `<XAxis>` to display the date as a str, however as I have the dataKey set to the date the `<XAxis> type` has to be `"category"` or it breaks.  But in order to have the domain shrink I need the type to be `"number"`.

Is there anyway to have a zoom/highlight line graph in recharts with date strings?  And if not how do I have the dataKey use the index position of the graph without adding anything to the dataset?

Thanks!